# providing critical section for threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

In this c++ program , I have created 10 threads which race to each other to acquire critical section.For this mean I'm using conditional variable as below code.The dispatcher in this program will grant one thread at a time to enter critical section.But there is a subtle problem. when dispatcher grant to a thread to enter , it will set ready_pipe variable true. If one new thread comes at this time (before consumer set ready_pipe=flase) newcomer thread will across the critical section without permission.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

std::condition_variable con_var_pipe;
bool ready_pipe = false;
std::mutex pipe_mutex;

bool critical_section_is_free=true;

void dispatcher()
{

    while(true)
    {

        if(critical_section_is_free)
        {
            critical_section_is_free=false;

            // send signal to a thread to enter critical section
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(pipe_mutex);
            ready_pipe = true;
            con_var_pipe.notify_one();

        }
    }
}


void consumer()
    {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(pipe_mutex);

    /* The Problem is Here at below line.When a new thread comes, 
      it will pass through this block because it see ready_pipe is true!!!*/

    con_var_pipe.wait(lk, [] {return ready_pipe;});

    /// critical section starts
    ready_pipe=false;
    /// here accessing pipe is occurring .

    /// critical section ends
    critical_section_is_free=true;


}

 int main()
    {
    std::thread allThreads[10];

    for(int i = 0 ; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        allThreads[i]=std::thread(consumer);
    }

    thread disp(dispatcher);

    for(int i = 0 ; i< 6 ; i++)
    {
        allThreads[i].join();
    }

    disp.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Further more , this code is also deficient because of a while(true) statement in dispatcher function and make busy waiting.

So the questions are :

1-how to create mutual exclusion when new thread comes.

2-how to avoid busy waiting in dispatcher() function.

3-and how threads be served in order as they come and register in wait().

Comment: There isn't actually a question in there anywhere. What question do you have about making the changes you discuss? What do you need help with?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sir, when a new thread reaches to wait(), it can go through critical section if see ready_pipe==true. but only one thread should get through at a time( which dispatcher has granted and set ready_pipe= true for it).

Comment: Right. So what's your question? Do you need an algorithm? If so, ask for one. Do you need an implementation? If so, describe the algorithm you need implemented. It's impossible to tell what help you need.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I need some modification in my code(or any recommendation) to avoid the noted problems.

Comment: Right, I get that. So what's stopping you from making those modifications? What don't you know? What are you stuck on? Have you figured out the algorithms you want to use? If not, ask for help with them. If so, describe them and ask for help with implementing them. You've stated a problem but not asked a specific question about it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think critical Section is a general problem and if some one could answer my question , many others could use it later. I found nothing on the web ....

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer your question yet because you haven't stated what your question actually is. I have no idea what you would search for on the web because, again, I don't know what your question is. I'm honestly trying to help. What's stopping you from writing the code you need? What do you get stuck on? What don't you know how to do? Have you worked out an algorithm? If not, sketch out what you have and ask for help on that. If you have, describe your algorithm and explain where you're stuck implementing it. I honestly can't figure out what you want.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The algorithm is classic read/consumer problem. readers want to access pipe in mutual exclusion way. I have a idea for implementing it using bool vector to identify exactly which thread can get through ,BUT , it can't do it in same order that thread comes. I need a queue for threads that can register their request mutually. Conditional variable provide queue , but there i cannot provide mutual exclusion in my code.Any way I thank you Sir. may be sometime i will found the modification which needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use two counters and a boolean to implement a basic "take a number" scheme.

One counter, `released_thread`, indicates which thread may proceed. This is logically equivalent to the "now serving" indicator.

The other, `next_waiter`, indicates which thread waits next. This is logically equivalent to the next number that will be taken

A boolean indicates whether the thread is permitted to proceed and when it is finished, so the executive knows when to call the next number.

The algorithms are as follows:

**To wait**:

1. Acquire the lock.
2. Note the value of the `next_waiter` variable and increment it.
3. Broadcast (notify all) the condition variable.
4. Wait on the condition variable until the boolean is true and the `released_thread` counter is equal to the value noted in step 2.
5. Release the lock.
6. When finished, acquire the lock, set the boolean to false, broadcast the condition variable, and release the lock.

**Executive**:

1. Acquire the lock.
2. Wait on the condition variable until the boolean is false and `next_waiter` is not equal to `released_thread`.
3. Increment `released_thread` and set the boolean to true.
4. Broadcast the condition variable.
5. Go to step 2.

Comment: Thank you Sir. This is exactly what I want. using two integers is a very nice approach.

Comment: You might prefer to use two condition variables, one to release a waiter and one to notify the executive that a task is complete. Don't forget to broadcast the waiter condition variable (notify all).

Comment: yes of course. thanks so much again.I know Stack community is proud of you Sir. ;)